# Binding material table to api node table

Tags: angular

I want to connect rest api data source to material table. This works for simple table but material table doesn't show any data.

This is the markup for simple table that works fine:

```html
<!-- simple table -->
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let x of list_product">
            <td>{{x.id}}</td>
            <td>{{x.description}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<!-- end of simple table -->
```

But this markup for a material table doesn't show the data:

```html
<!-- material table -->
<table mat-table>
    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let x of list_product"> {{x.id}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let x of list_product"> {{x.description}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
<!-- end of material table -->
```

This is my Typescript code that call table from node:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { analyzeAndValidateNgModules } from '@angular/compiler';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-basic',
    templateUrl: './basic.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./basic.component.scss']
})
export class BasicComponent implements OnInit {

    public list_product:any=[];
    displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'description'];

    constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.get_data();
    }

    get_data()
    {
        this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/listp").subscribe(
            (res)=>{ 
                for(var i=0;i<res['length'];i++){
                    this.list_product.push(res[i]);
                }
            }//end res
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your simple table and material table works differently. Therefore -

1. in your template, you need to bind `list_product` to the `dataSource` property of `mat-table`
2. in your component code, you need to replace the `list_product` each time you receive a new response - populating `list_product` with items one by one will not update the table's `dataSource`.

Modify your table as -

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="list_product">
    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let product"> {{product.id}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let product"> {{product.description}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

and change the `get_data()` method to -

```js
get_data(){
    this.http.get<any>("http://localhost:3000/listp").subscribe(
            res => this.list_product = res
        );
}
```

For further details, check the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples)

Comment: @mahdi.gh Please edit your post and add the code to where you have declared and used `list_product`.

Comment: define before ngOnInit() :export class BasicComponent implements OnInit {
  
  public list_product:any=[];
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'description'];

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

Comment: @mahdi.gh There is a `Edit` link below your post. Click it, and extra code to the post, not here in the comments.

Comment: i belive is important that simple table show my data but mat table dont show therefor my ts file probobly is correct and problem is in html file

Comment: @mahdi.gh Your simple table and mat-table works in different way. Have you checked the examples in the documentation? I added the link in the answer.

Comment: yes i see your link but this tables in material sites works with element list and not work with api address

Comment: @mahdi.gh Ok, change the `public list_product:any=[];` to `public list_product:any[]=[];` and use the `get_data()` method from my answer. See if it works then.

Comment: error TS2322: Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.

Comment: @mahdi.gh In the `get_data()` method change method call `this.http.get()` to `this.http.get<any>()`. I have edited it in the answer too. Check that to be clear.

Comment: hi atiyar,you help me yesterday and thank you.

Comment: i want another help ,and this is pagination for my table,for diffrents my project with other sample in web i can't resolve it.

Comment: @mahdi.gh You are welcome. If this answer fixed your issue you can mark it as `Accepted` by clicking the `Check` mark beside the answer. And/or upvote/downvote the answer using the Up/Down arrows above the `Check` mark.

Comment: how to bind paginator to list_product?

Comment: OK,checked it,.

Comment: @mahdi.gh I'd suggest you post another question for the paginator issue, mentioning the issue clearly. I will of course, try to help.

Answer (score 0):

i want another help ,and this is pagination for my table,for diffrents my project with other sample in web i can't resolve it

Comment: This is not a question, this is an answer you posted. Please delete this. I suggested you to post a new question with detail of you paginator issue. There is a big blue "Ask Question" button at the top right of the page. Use that.

Comment: how-to-pagination-angular-material-datatable-that-bind-to-api-link